# Поиск циклов в данных

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

Пытаюсь найти циклы в данных представленных ниже. Как сделать это правильно и эффективно?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.misc import electrocardiogram

x = electrocardiogram()[2000:4000]

plt.plot(x)
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Под поисками циклов вы понимаете поиск периодических колебаний максимальными амплитудами?

Если да, то вам нужно построить спектр сигнала и найти частоты с максимальными амплитудами.

Пусть ваша ЭКГ снималась с частотой `F` отсчетов в секунду (частота дискретизации). Тогда спектр можно вычислить средствами [`scipy.signal.periodogram`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.periodogram.html). Эта функция возвращает два массива - частоты и спектральную плотность сигнала, которая в простейшем случае равна просто квадрату модуля соотвествующего члена в разложении Фурье.

```
freqs, psd = signal.periodogram(x, fs=F)
plt.plot(freqs, psd)
```

Получится что-то такое:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для упрощения картинки можно отбросить высокие частоты. Например, все частоты выше 4 Гц (т.е. сокращения сердца чаще, чем 240 в минуту)

```
low_freqs = freqs[freqs < 4.0]
psd_low_freqs = psd[:len(low_freqs)]
plt.plot(low_freqs, psd_low_freqs)
```

В результате картинка станет заметно менее "зубастой"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я взял для примера кардиограмму из набора данных https://data.mendeley.com/datasets/7dybx7wyfn/3

Для выбранной кардиограммы получил частоту с максимальной амплитудой: `freqs[np.argmax(psd)]` результат равен `1.3`

Частоты, соответствующие наибольшим амплитудам в нижней части спектра:

```
idx = np.argsort(psd_low_freqs)
idx_most = idx[-3:]
print(low_freqs[idx_most], psd_low_freqs[idx_most])
```

Результат

```
array([3.9, 2.6, 1.3]), array([1662.1819, 5103.5654, 9900.397 ], dtype=float32)
```

Код, данные и графики можно посмотреть в [блокноте Junyper](https://github.com/pakuula/StackOverflow/blob/main/python/1294279/ecg.ipynb).

Там же добавлен пример обработки средствами быстрого преобразования Фурье, без периодограммы.